# How to mutate a column for the number at risk (survival)

Tags: r, dplyr, survival-analysis

As a personal exercise, I was wondering how to generate a column for the number at risk, or the number of observations that have not yet experienced the event at time *t*.

Here's some sample data:

```
df <- tibble(
  event = c(1,1,1,0,0),
  time = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50)
)
df
```

The desired output should look like:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  event  time nrisk
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1    10     4
2     1    20     3
3     1    30     2
4     0    40     2
5     0    50     2
```

Comment: if you start with `n_risk`, `n_risk - cumsum(df$event) + 1`

Comment: You want to create a new column called `n_risk` which is not present in your data. What is the logic to create that? How do you get value as 4, 3, 2, 2, 2?

Comment: Let event be death for simplicity's sake. At time 10, 4 people are still alive. At time 20, only 3 people will still be alive because individuals 1 and 3 have died, At time 40, 2 people are still alive because individuals 1,2,and 3 have died. Does that make more sense

Comment: Didn't understand how at time 20 individual 1 and 3 have died?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, I meant individuals 1 and 2

Comment: Just to add, `survfit` function of `survival` package automatically computes nrisk and other estimates (ncensor, ndeath, S(t) etc.) ex. `survival::survfit(survival::Surv(time=time, event=event) ~ 1, data=df) %>% broom::tidy()`

Comment: yup, I use the survival package quite extensively! I just wanted to know how to calculate on my own

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If every row is an individual you could subtract number of rows in the dataframe with cumulative sum of `event`.

```
df$n_risk <- nrow(df) - cumsum(df$event)
df

#  event  time n_risk
#  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#1     1    10      4
#2     1    20      3
#3     1    30      2
#4     0    40      2
#5     0    50      2
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    mutate(n_risk = n() - cumsum(event))
# A tibble: 5 x 3
#  event  time n_risk
#  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#1     1    10      4
#2     1    20      3
#3     1    30      2
#4     0    40      2
#5     0    50      2
```